# Gathering consecutive information from SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

I am using sybase.

I have a table with columns named time and quantity. Quantity can be either zero or non-zero. I need to find all the cases where for any time any subsequent quantity within 1 sec is > 0 and original quantity is greater than 40.

I am not able to think this problem in terms of SQL structure but if it were a C++ code I would have easily done it using a for loop, etc.

Let me try to explain this with an example.

From the attached image where I have gathered the data in ascending time:

- Since quantity at 10.01.01.000 > 40 and 10.01.01.001 > 0 we include 10.01.01.000 in our shorted list
- We do not include 10.01.01.001 in our shorted list as even though quantity > 0 the next quantity within 1 second i.e. at 10.01.01.002 is 0
- Row 4 is not included in our sample as there is next even within 1 second

```
RowNumber   Time        Quantity

1        10:01:01.000     100

2        10:01.01.001     50

3        10:01:01.002      0

4        10:01.01.003    100

5        10:01:03.001    100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming by "next" you really mean next and there are not multiple records, then you can do this with `lead`.

```
select t.RowNumber, t.Time, t.Quantity
from (select t.*,
             lead(time, 1) over (order by time) as nextTime,
             lead(quantity, 1) over (order by time) as nextQuantity
      from t
     ) t
where datediff(ms, t.time. t.nexttime) <= 1000 and
      (t.Quantity > 40 and t.nextQuantity > 0)
```

If you do not have the `lead()` function, you can do this as follows:

```
select t.RowNumber, t.Time, t.Quantity
from (select t.*,
             (select min(time) from t t2 where t2.time > t.time) as nexttime
      from t
     ) left outer join
     t tnext
     on tnext.time = t.nexttime
where datediff(ms, t.time. tnext.time) <= 1000 and
      (t.Quantity > 40 and tnext.Quantity > 0)
```

Comment: Great thanks!! I have never used lead but I can see its use now. Also how do I modify the above code of yours if I also had a Category column where the above data was for Category named 'A' and we have similar data for category named 'B' and so on. And we want to find the relevant sample for each category.

Comment: You would modify the statement after `over`:  `over (partition by category order by time)`.

Comment: Thanks!! Will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: The above code gives syntax error near 'over'. Can someone please help? I am assuming the name of table in my example is 't'.

Comment: Also at location ' from t) t' how does this work. We start with table named 't' and call it 't' again?

Comment: @user1949158 . . . "t" is an alias and can be re-used.  Aliases have a scope associated with them.  Here on SO, I tend to just use simple aliases such as "t" and use them over and over because they are easy to type.  And, what version of Sybase are you using?  Not all versions support `lead`.

Comment: I am a bit new to this. This is all I could find: Adaptive Server IQ 12.00.0000

Comment: Is there any other way other than using 'lead'? Thanks for your help.